# Passing constructors and Data as arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-prelude

I am trying to build a small error checker for a game I am working on and I am unsure of how to pass Data types as arguments. here is what I am trying to do
this is the file where my data arguments are

```
-- | Represents the type of move played in a 'GameState'.
data Played = Played ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -- ^ A "normal" move.
            | Passed                          -- ^ A (legal) pass.
            | Goofed ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -- ^ An illegal move, penalty applied.
            | Init                            -- ^ No one has moved yet.
            | UpgradedPawn2Knight (Int,Int)   -- ^ A pawn reached the other side when <2 knights.
            | PlacedPawn ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -- ^ A pawn that's been placed in any empty space after having reached the far end of the board.
            | BadPlacedPawn ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) -- ^ A strategy has attempted to do a pawn placement, but chose an invalid location.
```

And here is my code trying to implement a function based on these game states

```
prevPenalty :: Played -> Int
prevPenalty Init = 0
prevPenalty Goofed ((a, b),(c, d)) = 1
prevPenalty Passed ((a, b),(c, d)) = 0


currentPenalty :: Played -> Int
currentPenalty Goofed ((a, b),(c, d)) = 1 + prevPenalty
currentPenalty Passed ((a, b),(c, d)) = 0 + prevPenalty
```

However, at compile time this error appears

```
Penalty.hs:22:1:
    Equations for ‘prevPenalty’ have different numbers of arguments
      Penalty.hs:22:1-20
      Penalty.hs:23:1-38

Penalty.hs:28:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> t1’ with actual type ‘Int’
    The equation(s) for ‘currentPenalty’ have two arguments,
    but its type ‘Played -> Int’ has only one
```

I cant figure out how else to fix this... Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: in the function definition, put the entire pattern inside parenthesis like `(Goofed ...)`

Comment: also it's a bit strange to mix the valid with some invalid states - why don't you just represent the valid ones and use some score/game counter to account for penalties (I guess you will anyway)

Comment: btw @behzad.nouri you should make this into an answer ;)